# Source for a ledger

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin

Considering a block chain to store information on buying and selling of a houses. From where do the block chain obtain information ? From where information about litigation in the property can be obtained?

Answer (score 0):

This project won 3rd place in a hackathon this year and has an example about your question. It may help you: https://youtu.be/-y0WGwzKaxI